# Can no longer see line number of a css style in chrome dev tools when inspecting an element

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This has just became an issue today and was wondering if i've maybe touched something I shouldn't have but if you have a look at this picture here

[image: What dev tools should show]

This was taken from twitch just because i had a tab open, as you can see it has the css file that the style comes from and also the line number as per usual.

Now for some reason all of my web projects that I launch locally no longer have this on the dev tools and my tools look like this.

[image: What my devtools show]

This is making development pretty damn annoying as with the way I work I generally need the line numbers there when I'm doing quick changes to styles. Right now I have to Ctrl + F the class to make changes which is a pain.

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks pretty much like crbug.com/422073. This should be working in latest Chrome Canary

Answer (score 0):

I discovered, having the same problem, that if you are working with *local* files, Chrome will not show the line number. You have to upload them, and then the line number will show up.

I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Yeah it is very annoying, I still have the issue sadly. I dont have it on my surface pro that I work on as well depending on the day.