# CSS without source link while element inspecting

Tags: css, google-chrome

while I'm element inspecting on my website. I can see that there is css loading on the webpage, however, I can't see where this CSS is coming from.

[image]

Normally there is a link towards the CSS file floated on the right, this time there isn't, does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Might be Javascript if the declaration is at the top

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276956/can-no-longer-see-line-number-of-a-css-style-in-chrome-dev-tools-when-inspecting

Comment: Can you find any connection in Sources or Network tabs? Or possible provide a link to the site?

Comment: View it on the mobile, you'll see some white toggle slides. It has a span h4 in it. it's http://groeske.nl/leerwerk-trajecten/#1507985130707-9cfecb22-a507

Comment: Those are definitely internal styles, you can find them embedded in the page wrapped in `<style>` tags, under the comment `Custom CSS Codes` (probably custom embedded theme styles), by viewing the page source (Ctrl+U) or by viewing the Network tab, selecting the first initiator and selecting the "Response" tab. Why it doesn't reference the source of those files as `index.php` or something similar I can't say.